# How to talk about not being satisfied with some degrees of something?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is there a a natural sentence or phrase describing a state of not being satisfied?

> E.LL is a writer. He has written a piece of writing recently. He thinks his work can be improved although it already seems acceptable. He never was a big fan of perfectionism, but surprisingly, that current point of perfection didn't satisfy him and he continued to modify the the piece of writing .... (These  sentences has been concocted by me)
>
> ```
> Added: consider we have three basic discrete levels of writers: !
> 1)careless 2)moderate 3)perfect
> And also there are some other levels that 
> lies within these three levels !
> And the writer creates a piece of writing whose 
> work qualifies him such way that he locates between level 2 and 3
> which is referred to it as 
> **that** in the above sentence.
> ```

Is there a natural way to write/speak about that? In Persian, we have a phrase , **بسنده نکرد** , which fits to this context completely.

Also, which one of the below quantifiers* are more appropriate in such sentences?

1. that point of
2. that extent of
3. that degree of
4. that level of
5. that scale of
6. that deal of

---

***quantifiers** does not stand for its grammarian connotation, it is just a word that came to my mind at the moment.

Comment: You're looking to replace "that point of perfection", right?  He wasn't satisfied with its imperfections and continued to modify.... We can say "He was unhappy with its imperfections..."

Comment: **Content**: [to make yourself accept something as satisfactory, although it could be better:
We had to content ourselves with watching the sea lions from the shore.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/content)

Comment: @TRomano Not exactly, I want to know the proper phrase for expressing the amount of perfection, **that**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like either proofreading or a request for writing advice

Comment: @Sina Thanks for the suggestion, do you sure it is a natural word in this context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although I do not know how one would learn to write naturally without asking any questions, feel free for closing it bro.

Comment: Write it this way: He was not a big fan of perfectionism, but he didn't content himself with that point of perfection and continued to modify the artifact/book/piece of writing/ .... It seems good for me, but you can ask @Snailplane.

Comment: There are several errors in your text ("he didn't satisfy with" is syntactic gibberish, and there's nothing to contextualize what "that" refers to, for example). It's not realistic to address all these points without focusing on "writing advice", since the entire construction you're trying to "fine-tune" simply isn't a good starting point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought people who answer would not have problem to interpret that **that**

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with **"he didn't satisfy with" is syntactic gibberish**. I corrected it

Comment: @Cardinal: I'm guessing "that point of perfection" is supposed to refer to *the level of perfection attained in an earlier draft*, but it might just as easily refer to *the level of perfection that the writer was not a big fan of*. Just because you've got some *vague* idea of what OP is trying to say, doesn't mean you fully understand it.

Comment: The edit doesn't help *me* understand. I've pointed out twice now that it's not clear what ***that*** (level of perfection) refers to. It would be helpful if you could write something which *exactly* explains what you're trying to say (using completely different words, in several sentences, would probably be the best way).

Comment: Now I'm wonder if Cardinal is looking for  "meager" perfection. If perfection is on a sliding scale, he wants to know a word for something that barely made it onto the scale.

Comment: @TRomano Not exactly, I was declaring for FumbleFingers what **that** can mean. however, I accepted your answer, especially the **degree of perfection** collocation

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that what you mean by ***that** [level of perfection]* is actually something that could be paraphrased as *the (intermediate, not particularly low or high) level of perfection which arose naturally when the writer made no particular effort to **achieve** either a low or a high level of perfection*. The trouble is there simply isn't any natural way of referencing such a complex concept in the way you seek. You'd need to use far more words (not necessarily those of my paraphrasing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers In fact, I wanted to quantify with phrases mentioned in the questions, but as TRomano mentioned, such quantification sounds odd in English. You do not say a restaurant with food having low degree of deliciousness or a business with high level of reliability. instead, you use short words like unreliable business.

Comment: It';s true we don't normally refer to [level of deliciousness](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22level+of+deliciousness%22) (under 300 hits in the whole of Google Books), but [level of perfection](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22level+of+perfection%22) (60,000 hits) and [level of reliability](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22level+of+reliability%22) (141,000) are perfectly normal collocations. It's just that levels of *perfection* are nearly always high, and *reliability* is usually high or low, not "somewhere in the middle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepting, for the sake of argument, that perfection is not an all-or-nothing thing:

> not satisfied with that **degree** of perfection

[was the usual collocation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=degree%20of%20perfection&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdegree%20of%20perfection%3B%2Cc0), at least back when people were concerned with perfection :)

though one could substitute **point, pitch, standard, height, state, level**.

Comment: I have added something, wish those reveals my thoughts effectively

Comment: Your addendum is not as clear as it might be. Are you asking for a word that  characterizes something (e.g. a performance, a written work) as falling somewhere between "average" and "excellent"? Or are you merely showing a possible referent for "that"? As in, "I asked you to turn up the volume, but I didn't want it *that* loud."

Comment: No I meant to use the best or natural describer* like **degree of perfection** in that context.

Comment: I find it very odd that you would say "That work has a very low degree of perfection" or a "very careless degree of perfection".  Why even use the word **perfection** when imperfections outnumber or outweigh the good points?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have used adverbs rather than adjectives, let me change it

Comment: No, I mean the word **perfection**.  Do you mean "accomplishment"? or "achievement"?

Comment: I don't now, Perhaps since I am not a native or advanced English speaker. but, I my native language, we can use quantifiers with perfection, e.g., a careless writer who has almost no regard for spelling correctly, this writer locates on the careless point! I think I should make further modifications.

Comment: To say of "slipshod" or "careless" workmanship that it was of "a very low degree of perfection" would be understood as sarcasm. That would be an unusual turn of phrase.  It would be like saying "the food at that restaurant is of a low degree of deliciousness".  Normal, idiomatic would be "not very good", which would mean "mediocre" or even "bad".

Comment: Although I am learning formal English and my questions revolve around the formal contexts, I think I got my answer = **It would be like saying "the food at that restaurant is of a low degree of deliciousness". Normal, idiomatic would be "not very good", which would mean "mediocre" or even "bad"**